# how to bulk change owner ( or other fields) in ms dynamics crm 2013?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, bulk

In Dynamics CRM 2011, we could export accounts to excel and import again to bulk edit fields (I didn't test). But in 2013, users could only export "this page" account for bulk edit.

Now I need to change accounts owner, accounts number is over 20,000. Manually editing is almost impossible.

I could edit them to modify directly on database. Obviously, it's not a safe way.

Anyone have better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are referring to this window:

[image]

you still need to select the checkbox "Make this data..." also when you select the second radio button option. the file will contain all the records for re-import.

the interface is misleading.

Comment: You are right. I really couldn't understand why MS made a simple and clear interface to be confused and misleading.